# ionic 2 show file download progress in notification

Tags: ionic2

[image]

i want to show the download notification as in the image. i'm am using ionic 2 Cordova file transfer

Comment: Ok then good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova file transfer will download the file, but will not show a progress bar in the notification center. The progress bar is displayed when you use the [download manage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager)r of native android to perform the download. While Ionic Native does not contain a plugin that can do this, there are a few that work. 
https://github.com/vasani-arpit/cordova-plugin-downloadmanager & https://github.com/emilbayes/cordova-plugin-android-downloadmanager