# implement download notification file ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, download-manager

I have the following dilemma, I am working with Ionic 3 and I have a class that downloads a file from a URL that brings me a REST service. This download the file without problems but I have not known how to implement or I have not searched correctly to add a download notification as shown in the following link:
[ionic 2 show file download progress in notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43471375/ionic-2-show-file-download-progress-in-notification)

Inside the link there are 2 answers corresponding to how to add the library but I do not know if they are also compatible with IOS since I need them to be for android and IOS.
I currently work with file.transfer to save the file on the device. I leave the code below:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => { 

  this.databaseService.getSesion(2).then(result => {
    this.rutUsuario = result.valor;
    })
  .catch( error => {
  });

  if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
    this.storageDirectory = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
  }
  else if(this.platform.is('android')) {
    this.storageDirectory = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + '/Download/';

    /**
   * Permisos de Android
   */

    this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).then(
      result => {
        if (result.hasPermission) {
          // code
        } else {
          this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).then(result => {
            if (result.hasPermission) {
              // code
            }
          });
        }
      },
      err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    );
  }
  else {
    // exit otherwise, but you could add further types here e.g. Windows
    return false;
  }
});
  }
if(respuesta.status == "200") {
        let autorizacion = this.resultado.headers;
        let nombreArchivo = datos.split("tmp/");
        let urlFinal = datos;

        fileTransfer.download(urlFinal , this.storageDirectory  + nombreArchivo[1]).then((entry) => {  
          this.alerta("Se ha descargado el archivo de manera satisfactoria.");
          this.loading.dismissAll();
          this.databaseService.GuardaSQLlite(1, autorizacion.authorization);
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
        }, (error) => {
          this.alerta("Hubo un error al momento de descargar el archivo. Si el problema persiste favor contactarse al 816 35 12 o 816 35 09.");
          this.loading.dismissAll();
        });
```

If someone had a website with an example of how it is implemented correctly I would appreciate it since I am somewhat blocked at this time and I can not find a solution.

The help given in advance is greatly appreciated